# need jquery datepicker to fire again for changing a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When i click in an empty textbox, the datepicker fires and the calendar dialog shows nicely. But if click again on a date in the textbox in order to change to a new date, I cannot cause the same datepicker dialog to pop up.

Markup after page is loaded follows:

```
<div id="panelVacationMode" class="row">
    <span class="labelCell" title="Skip reminder emails until I return"> 
    <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$CheckBox1" 
     checked="checked"><label for="CheckBox1">Vacation Mode</label></span>
    <div id="vacationModeBox" class="vacationRangeCell">
        <label for="txtFromDate" id="lblStart">Start:</label> 
            <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtFromDate" type="text" 
               value="11/1/2016" maxlength="10" 
               id="txtFromDate" class="dateTextBox" size="8">
        <label for="txtToDate" id="lblReturn">Return:</label> 
            <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtToDate" type="text" 
               value="12/31/2016" maxlength="10" 
               id="txtToDate" class="dateTextBox" size="8">
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>    
</div>
```

Here is the code at the bottom of the .aspx page:

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        // check if checkbox is unchecked 
        if ($("#CheckBox1").is(':checked'))
            $('#vacationModeBox').show();
        else
            $('#vacationModeBox').hide();
        // check if any checkbox has changed state
        $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
            $('#txtFromDate').focus();
            $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
                    $('.dateTextBox').val("");
                    $('#vacationModeBox').toggle(this.checked);
                }
                else
                    $('#txtFromDate').focus();
        });
        $(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
                }

            });
            $('#txtToDate').focus();
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update added 14-Oct-2016:**

Perhaps I need some changes to these references below to make **datepicker** work for me as described in the original post? :

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" /> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/IEStyles.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/StyleSheet1.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/app.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/sitewide.js") %>"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ExtraStyles" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Striving to be clear: when I click on a textbox without a date already stored, the datepicker UI "pops up" nicely with the calendar exposed for choosing; yet when I click in a textbox already with a date with the intention of picking a new date, nothing happens. Even if I clear the mm/dd/yyyy value out and then try to click for datepicker, nothing happens. Here is a sample of where I cannot interact with datepicker:
[image: once set to a date, I cannot change]

**Update 15 Oct:** (no change after use of newest frameworks)
The following screen snippet shows use of the newer resources yet datepicker behaves the same for me as in the OP:
[image: no response from datepicker if date already present]

Comment: Not that it matters, but you don't need to have nested `$(function () {` blocks. Just one containing set is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i updated your whole source code...
now it seems that it will work...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelVacationMode" class="row">
    <span class="labelCell" title="Skip reminder emails until I return"> 
    <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$CheckBox1" 
     checked='checked'><label for="CheckBox1">Vacation Mode</label></span>
    <div id="vacationModeBox" class="vacationRangeCell">
        <label for="txtFromDate" id="lblStart">Start:</label> 
            <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtFromDate" type="text" 
               value="11/1/2016" maxlength="10" 
               id="txtFromDate" class="dateTextBox" size="8">
        <label for="txtToDate" id="lblReturn">Return:</label> 
            <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtToDate" type="text" 
               value="12/31/2016" maxlength="10" 
               id="txtToDate" class="dateTextBox" size="8">
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>    
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
                }

            });
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
                }
            });
});
$(function () {
        // check if checkbox is unchecked 
        if ($("#CheckBox1").is(':checked')){
            $('#vacationModeBox').show();
        $('#txtFromDate').focus();
    }
        else
            $('#vacationModeBox').hide();

        // check if any checkbox has changed state
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
                    $('.dateTextBox').val("");
                    $('#vacationModeBox').toggle(this.checked);
                }
                if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $('#txtFromDate').focus();
        }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I know the code is working as is but I don't see from your answer how to make the datepicker dialog widget show again when the user wants to change the (existing) date value to a different date. The behavior I am seeking needs to work for both text boxes (i.e. both datepickers). In short, I don't see any "answer" in your reply above.

Comment: actually in my browser i am able to select the dates again.. in both of the boxes.... 
everything is working fine...
just put a glance on this line.. may be this is the issue...
if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
i think it should be checked instead of :checked

otherwise try changing the browser...

Comment: make sure that you have included all three libraries of jquery in the code..

jquery.min.js
jquery-ui.min.js
and
jquery-ui-ui.css

try shifting all these library above the actual code written by you...

Comment: See update to OP (original post). My jquery is at the bottom of the page and should run after DOM is loaded. Maybe I need new jquery ui ?

Comment: Sanjeev, if you are still with me, please know you can EDIT your answer to provide actual code rather than these cryptic snippets via comments. Also, I cannot switch to another browser on my dev machine; has to work first in Chrome.

Comment: Sanjeev, please see update to OP showing use of latest libraries. I hope I have clearly explained the problem. Feels like I need to add something like    "onClick:" to datepickers but I am guessing since I don't understand really what happens with "onSelect:" and I found no "onClick:" in the documentation.

Comment: sorry for late reply, actually is wasn't online... and was busy in offline projects...

Comment: Sanjeev, thank you very much for your help. Your reputation is sure to grow quickly! As I see now what you did was simply to re-order 2 document ready functions. First, establish the behavior of the datepicker widget and then deal with the checkbox changes(show and hide) and the focus. Other than that, I cannot quite explain why your re-arrangement of script works and my original did not. In any case, I thank you for your efforts to help me, a jquery rookie.

Comment: actually... what happens that... whatever function you are calling or whichever variables you are trying to access... must be loaded into the memory... before it can be used... and that's the reason... sometimes we get confused that code is correct but why it's behaviour is unexpected